# Understanding of below sentence

Tags: sentence

I’m writing an email but I wonder whether  the below sentence is clear to understand. If it isn’t understandable  show me up the correction.

That the orders have been delayed we have decided to happen the cancellation of our orders.

Comment: You might want to include a longer description of what you're trying to get across because the sample sentence is very unclear.

Comment: Are you the seller or the buyer?

Comment: It isn't "understandable" and it's difficult for us to correct it because we don't understand what you are trying to say!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you are trying to convey with this sentence, but it seems that what you want to say is that you are cancelling your orders because they have been delayed. Here are a few options to convey that with more clarity:

> Because of the delays experienced with our orders we have decided to
>   cancel them.

or

> We have decided to cancel our orders due to the fact that they have
>   been delayed.

or

> Given the delay we have decided to cancel our orders.